# Slow MySQL InnoDB performance of table with 100 million rows

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have the database in this format.

```
CREATE TABLE `dna` (
 `p_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `dna_bits` bit(32) NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`),
 KEY `dna_bits` (`dna_bits`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Currently, I have 100 millions rows and I need to query quickly by dna_bits which I have an index on.

My query looks like

```
select CONV(dna_bits, 16, 2) as bits, user_id from dna where dna_bits in (b'010101', b'0101011', ...)
```

Searching 10000 dna_bits in where clause took me over 8 seconds.

EXPLAIN on my shorten* query showed this.

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  dna range   dna_bits    dna_bits    4   NULL    77  Using where
```

I'm running MySQL server on my iMac 3.2 GHz Intel Core i5 with 16GB RAM.

What can I do to speed up the process?

Thanks.

Comment: what is in the "in (...)" clause?  In clauses can be very inefficient.  Since you are getting 10000 of them, I suspect you have a subquery in the **in** clause which will absolutely kill your query.

Comment: It's just pure bits query. Where (b'010101', b'0101000', ...)

Comment: You actually listed 10000 hardcoded items in your query, or did you use a subquery to get that list from another table?

Comment: hard coded. I generated those values before querying.

Answer (score 1):

Are there multiple rows for each `dna_bits`?  If not, then that column could be the `PRIMARY KEY`?  If you can do that, then the speed might double because you won't be bouncing between the secondary index and the PK.  Getting rid of p_id and the secondary key would save space.

How much RAM?  How big is the table?  (I would guess 5GB data+index.)  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  If that can be set to 70% of available RAM and still be bigger than the table size, then (eventually) all the data you need will be cached.  Again a speedup.  (Can't tell how much.)  This is because of avoiding I/O.

10K lookups will take *some* time.